# How can I deserialize this JSON to a C# object?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to figure out how to create a C# class that I can deserialize this json into.
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Here is my json

```
{
"0": {
    "heading": "Home",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": {}
},
"1": {
    "heading": "About",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": {
        "0": {
            "name": "Programs",
            "value": "programs"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Sample Page",
            "value": "test"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Donations",
            "value": "donations"
        }
    }
},
"2": {
    "heading": "Products",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": {}
},
"3": {
    "heading": "Contact Us",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": {
        "0": {
            "name": "Programs",
            "value": "programs"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Donations",
            "value": "donations"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've tried the following, with no luck

```
public class Menu
{
    public MenuItem MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public DropDownMenu DropDownMenu { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownMenu
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }   
}
```

In my controller I'm using the following to try and deserialize the json into my object.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddMenu(string menuType, string menu, string menuTitle)
 {
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var newMenu = serializer.Deserialize<Menu>(menu);
  }
```

Note: The menu variable contains the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Your current JSON has 4 menu items in it... I am guessing that could change to 5 or 6, right?... if so... your JSON is incorrect, you should use an array.

Something like:

```
[
{
    "heading": "Home",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": []
},
{
    "heading": "About",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": [
        {
            "name": "Programs",
            "value": "programs"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sample Page",
            "value": "test"
        },
        {
            "name": "Donations",
            "value": "donations"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "heading": "Products",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": []
},
{
    "heading": "Contact Us",
    "link": "#",
    "dropdown": [
        {
            "name": "Programs",
            "value": "programs"
        },
        {
            "name": "Donations",
            "value": "donations"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And then define your class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string heading
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string link
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DropDownMenu[] dropdown
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DropDownMenu
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON as an "Array of MenuItems"... like:

```
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var newMenu = ser.Deserialize<MenuItem[]>(json);
```

Hope that helps,

Daniel.

Comment: This results in an exception, stating that there is no parameterless constructor defined for MenuItem[]. If I define it, I still receive the exception.

Comment: I just tested in a Mvc 4 site (.Net 4.5) and it works fine. You can see it in this screecast: http://screencast.com/t/slucdqpK5

Answer (score 0):

From [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx):

> ASP.NET MVC 3 includes built-in JSON binding support that enables
>   action methods to receive JSON-encoded data and model-bind it to
>   action method parameters.

Instead of receiving the parameter as `string` you could try binding the request directly to your object (**json model binding**):

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddMenu(string menuType, Menu menu, string menuTitle)
 {
   // use menu here, no need to deserialize anything else
  }
```

Also, make sure the client sends the request's content type as json, for example:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

[See Phil Haack's example](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

[Here](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx) and [here](http://theshravan.net/json-binding-support-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) are two more.

Comment: Deserialize won't take an object, it has to be as follows.

Deserialize<object>(string); // this is the function signature.

Comment: Of course it works, do you mind showing me documentation that states otherwise? I've added a few more examples (including a link to Phil Hacck's blog) showing json model binding.

Comment: Added one more link to ScottGu's blog